# How to setup Flask-SQLAlchemy to gracefully manage PostgreSQL unavailability at startup

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask API, everything is working ok and everything is Dockerized for local testing, this is the flask **init**.py:

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname

import cloudinary
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.flask import FlaskIntegration
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

cors = CORS()
marsh = Marshmallow()
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address)

from deblurrer.api import api_bp


def create_app(config='flask_config.Production'):
    """
    Init core application.

    Args:
        config: can be import to object or the object itself

    Returns:
        Application instance
    """
    # Load .env vars
    dotenv_path = join(dirname(dirname(__file__)), '.env')
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

    # Setup default production config
    app = Flask('deblurrer', instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(config)

    # Sentry config
    sentry_sdk.init(
        dsn=os.environ.get('SENTRY_DNS'),
        integrations=[FlaskIntegration()]
    )

    # Init Cloudinary credentials
    cloudinary.config(
        cloud_name = os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'),
        api_key = os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'),
        api_secret = os.environ.get('CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'),
    )

    # Init Plugins
    cors.init_app(app)
    marsh.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    limiter.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

        # Create tables for models
        db.create_all()

        return app
```

When I do `docker-compose up`, the PostgreSQL Container is not granted to boot before the Flask API Container, which is normal and expected. It is recommended to prepare the API to gracefully manage database unavailability at any point, including the start time.

My question is, how I can do this on my flask application? seems that this must be done on the **init**.py when initializing the Flask-SQLAlchemy, but i have no idea how, i tried to do some research, but nothing apparent arise, can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep trying...

```
# Connect to database
tries = 5
while tries > 0:
    try:
        db.create_all()
        tries = 0
    except:
        tries += -1
        print('Failed to connect to database. Waiting and then trying again (try countdown: %s)' % tries)
        sleep(10)  # Wait a bit until database is loaded
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i miss that db.create_all() manage the connection!